# Trying to make a method revive input form the console

Tags: java, netbeans

hey guys so ive been trying to get my method getConsole to work it is supposed to - ask for a input form the console an then return a scanner object, but i got no dice so far need help thx.

// getConssole is supposed to do the same as getInput, ask for a input form the console an then return a scanner object

```
public static Scanner getInput(String promte){
        return new Scanner(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(promte));
    }
```

// This is what i have for getConsole so far

```
public static Scanner getConsoleInput( String promte){
     return new Scanner (System.out.println(promte));
 }
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you try to achieve with this code ....

Comment: its just a simple exercise i ran to get a better handling of console input and system input.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to print the prompt using `System.out` and then create the `Scanner` using `System.in`:

```
public static Scanner getConsoleInput( String promte){
    System.out.print(promte);
    return new Scanner (System.in);
}
```

However, you should not create more than one `Scanner` based on `System.in` since the `Scanner` closes `System.in` when not used anymore. Make sure to only create one `Scanner` object and reuse that, like

```
private final static Scanner theScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static Scanner getConsoleInput( String promte){
    System.out.print(promte);
    return theScanner;
}
```

Make sure that no other part of your code also creates a `Scanner` based on `System.in`.